# AppFabric IIS Extensions

Tags: iis-7, appfabric

I've inherited an application that uses AppFabric hosted on an Win2K8R2 application server. I added the IIS feature to the server and I'm trying to get the IIS UI extensions installed. Can anyone advise on how to do that?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Just install AppFabric on your server ([download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115))

For IIS Extension, you only need to install **Hosting Administration**.
Note, if you server is hosting a WCF/WF services, you will also need **Hosting Services** : without this feature, your service will not use Appfabric event if it's enabled in the config.

[image]